# How to select distinct multi-column values in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct

I am trying to get distinct values with multi column select.

Sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE DUP_VALUES (ID NUMBER, NAME VARCHAR2(64));

 INSERT INTO DUP_VALUES values (1, 'TEST1');
 INSERT INTO DUP_VALUES values (2, 'TEST1');
 INSERT INTO DUP_VALUES values (3, 'TEST2');
 INSERT INTO DUP_VALUES values (4, 'TEST2');
 INSERT INTO DUP_VALUES values (5, 'TEST1');
 INSERT INTO DUP_VALUES values (6, 'TEST1');
 INSERT INTO DUP_VALUES values (7, 'TEST1');
```

I want to get

```
ID NAME
1  TEST1
3  TEST2
```

I tried with `SELECT DISTINCT ID, NAME FROM DUP_VALUES`

But, I got all values, because ID is unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
select min(id) as id, name
from dup_values
group by name;
```